# SQL Server Command Builder and AutoIncrementing IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have a SQL Server database that I'm pulling into a dataset to make changes, however, when I update any particular table using the `SqlDataAdapter`, it does not start the ID key at the same value that SQL is using.

I am utilizing a `SqlCommandBuilder` with the `SqlDataAdapter`. I've found this little nugget on MSDN:

> *The default UpdateRowSource value is Both unless the command is automatically generated (as in the case of the SqlCommandBuilder), in which case the default is None.*

That's great and all, but whenever I try to change that property on in my app, it stops executing at that line, but doesn't throw an exception.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I'd like to keep using the command builder, but I also need the autoincrement ID values to be concurrent.

```
FdaPoints.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM points;"
FdaPoints.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer several months ago and forgot to update my own question. You can append the command builder's insert command with this SQL statement:

> SELECT ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

So in the end the code looks something like this:

```
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("", conn)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd = SQLCommandBldr.GetInsertCommand.Clone
            cmd.CommandText += "; SELECT ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
            cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both
            da.InsertCommand = cmd
            da.UpdateCommand = SQLCommandBldr.GetUpdateCommand.Clone
            da.DeleteCommand = SQLCommandBldr.GetDeleteCommand.Clone
            da.Update(YourDataTable)
            da.Dispose()
```